# Meta Tags and Description for Manufacturer (opencart)

Tags: php, e-commerce, meta-tags, opencart

I am using OpenCcart 1.5.3
I need some guidance about how to add description and Meta tags (keywords and desc.) for Manufacturer?

I am unable to find any clue how to do so.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I did not used OpenCart before, but if it is open source like it says it can be done just need to be familiar with the app code.

In meantime you can use this, it is not free :( 
http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=654&filter_search=%20manufacturer%20meta%20keyword

Comment: thanks Dusan, actually i am looking for something which is not paid and usually any extention on opencart is paid it means its not easy to be done for someone who is not a superexpert in php :(

Answer (score 0):

I've found some solution at http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=38924
Hope, it can help

Comment: Please post full answers here, not just links that may soon die away.